# The final local variable "name" cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, visibility

I have this class:

```
class Tester{
    final String rigaFile=riga;
    final BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(reader2);

    fr.getList().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {


        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                //                  fr.getLabel().setText(fr.getList().getSelectedValue().toString());
                while(rigaFile!=null)
                {                   
                    String[] parts=rigaFile.split("\t");
                    for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
                    {
                        if(listaPath.get(i).equals(parts[1]) && parts[1].substring(parts[1].lastIndexOf('/')+1, parts[1].length()).equals(fr.getList().getSelectedValue().toString()))
                        {
                            fr.getLabel().setText(fr.getList().getSelectedValue().toString());
                        }

                    }
                    try {
                        rigaFile=r.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

The variable "rigaFile" throws the following error:
"The final local variable rigaFile can not be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type".
Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: What do you think the exception is telling you? It can't be any clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner classes can only access variables of the surrounding class when they are final. This means you can't change the reference. Since strings in java are immutable, you can't change its value as well.

One possible solution is using a final `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` and change its content inside your anonymous inner class.

```
final StringBuilder rigaFile = new StringBuilder(riga);
...
          try {
              rigaFile.setLength(0);
              rigaFile.append(r.readLine());
          } catch (IOException e1) {
```

You also have to change your while condition, since `rigaFile` will never be null. To get the string value of `rigaFile` you may write `rigaFile.toString()`.

Comment: You want to change `rigaFile`, which is declared in `Tester`, from inside your `ListSelectionListener`. This is not possible since it is and has to be final. The trick is to declare `rigaFile` as a `StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder`), because these are mutable, i.e. you can change the value of an existing object.